# Gradle Sync task with doLast doesn't work

Tags: gradle

The gradle task is working well:

```
task mySync1(type: Sync) {
    from "source-dir1"
    from "source-dir2"
    into "target-dir"
}
```

But if I add `doLast`, it doesn't nothing(and no errors):

```
task mySyncNotWorking(type: Sync) {
    doLast {
        from "source-dir1"
        from "source-dir2"
        into "target-dir-z"
    }
}
```

The correct one is:

```
task mySyncFixed() {
    doLast {
        project.sync {
            from "source-dir1"
            from "source-dir2"
            into "target-dir-z"
        }
    }
}
```

My question is the task `mySyncNotWorking`, the `from` and `into` methods are still belong to `Sync` if they are inside `doLast`? Why do they not work?

Answer (score 2):

> Why do they not work?

They do work, but **after** the task was executed. And you can't configure something **after** it was executed.

If you really need to configure your task during **execution phase**, maybe because you need to use the results of other tasks (but can't use task outputs for some reason), just use a `doFirst` closure.

The reason why nothing happens in your second example is the nothing-to-do check of the implemented task action. It is perfectly fine for a task to do nothing, this is not a reason for an error.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning "Execution phase", I just realize that my understand of gradle tasks is totally wrong, now I'm clear